# How to acess and filter a dictonary with multiple values?

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, pymongo

I am accessing a document in my MongoDB using pymongo.
Now I would like to filter the directory that is returned based on if the value standard is true.

Currenlty my code looks as follows:

```
db = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = db.myclient["pricing"]
mycol = mydb["locations"]

mydoc = db["pricing"]["prices"].find_one({"location":"test"})

for i in mydoc.items():
    print(i)
```

This code returns the following:

```
('_id', ObjectId('5f43c555dec06035ccfd2eac'))
('location', 'test')
('rent-40', {'titel': 'Base rent', 'price': 620, 'tooltip': 'test i think ', 'explenation': 'longer explanation', 'standard': False})
('rent-32', {'titel': 'Base rent', 'price': 600, 'tooltip': 'nana', 'explenation': 'very long explenation', 'standard': True})
('water', {'titel': 'Water cost', 'price': 10, 'tooltip': 'test', 'explenation': 'long explenation', 'standard': True})
  ('tv-38', {'titel': 'TV program', 'price': 5, 'tooltip': 'long', 'explenation': 'longer', 'standard': False})
('tv-70', {'titel': 'TV program', 'price': 5, 'tooltip': 'boring', 'explenation': 'very boring', 'standard': True})
```

The final result should be a list of the dictionaries where the `standard == True`.
I would be very thankful for help regarding this as I struggle with how the data is nested.

Maybe not the most elegant solution however it worked for me. The trouble was that the first two items are differently formated so I cut them away and then it worked quit simple:

```
standard = []
c =list(mydoc.items())
#print(c[2:])
for i in c[2:]:
    if i[1]["standard"] == True:
        standard.append(i)
else:
    print("hi")
print(standard)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow. You can use dict comprehension to filter the documents. In the example below `isinstance(v, dict)` checks that the item is an embedded document and `v.get('standard') is True` is your filter.

```
filtered_doc = {k: v for k, v in mydoc.items() if isinstance(v, dict) and v.get('standard') is True}
```

Worked example:

```
import pprint

mydoc = {
    'location': 'test',
    'rent-40': {'titel': 'Base rent', 'price': 620, 'tooltip': 'test i think ', 'explenation': 'longer explanation', 'standard': False},
    'rent-32': {'titel': 'Base rent', 'price': 600, 'tooltip': 'nana', 'explenation': 'very long explenation', 'standard': True},
    'water': {'titel': 'Water cost', 'price': 10, 'tooltip': 'test', 'explenation': 'long explenation', 'standard': True},
    'tv-38': {'titel': 'TV program', 'price': 5, 'tooltip': 'long', 'explenation': 'longer', 'standard': False},
    'tv-70': {'titel': 'TV program', 'price': 5, 'tooltip': 'boring', 'explenation': 'very boring', 'standard': True}}

filtered_doc = {k: v for k, v in mydoc.items() if isinstance(v, dict) and v.get('standard') is True}
pprint.pprint(filtered_doc)
```

Will give:

```
{'rent-32': {'explenation': 'very long explenation',
             'price': 600,
             'standard': True,
             'titel': 'Base rent',
             'tooltip': 'nana'},
 'tv-70': {'explenation': 'very boring',
           'price': 5,
           'standard': True,
           'titel': 'TV program',
           'tooltip': 'boring'},
 'water': {'explenation': 'long explenation',
           'price': 10,
           'standard': True,
           'titel': 'Water cost',
           'tooltip': 'test'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use list comprehension (if you don't want to filter it in the MongoDB itself):

```
filtered_items = [x for x in mydoc.items() if x[1]['standard']]
```

This will create a list of items where the second element (the returned dictionary) has value True (if it may happen that the key 'standard'  won't be there, just use  `x[1].get('standard', False)` instead)